# How to correctly paint a huge image

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm fairly new to wxWidgets so please bear with me. Let's say I have a 10Kx10K image and my wxScrolledWindow has a size of 640x480. I load the whole image into a wxBitmap which I use in my paint function.

Now in my OnPaint function I just say

```
wxPaintDC dc(this);
dc.DrawBitmap(_Bitmap, 0, 0 );
```

This somewhat works for the first few paints but soon the Window content is out order and artifacts appear. This happens very fast when I move a scroll bar back and forth very quickly.

I use the latest wxWidgets on a Windows 7 machine.

So, how can I improve my painting code?

Many thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something that might be helped by using double buffering.

The first thing to start trying is to replace wxPaintDC with [wxBufferedPaintDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxbufferedpaintdc.html#wxbufferedpaintdc)

For more suggestions, here is a wiki article on the subject: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Flicker-Free_Drawing

Answer (score 3):

Using a 10000x10000 wxBitmap is a bad idea on its own, it may simply fail to be created on an older system (that's 400MiB of video RAM!). Drawing it entirely is sheer madness.

I don't know where does your data come from but in a typical case of e.g. a map to be shown on screen, you should break it into tiles, convert the tiles that are currently visible on screen to wxBitmap (or several of them) and draw only those.

*Then* you may optimize your drawing by using double buffering (which is relatively useless under Windows 7 that double buffers everything on its own) and otherwise, but you should be using a reasonably-sized backing store bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

As Ravenspoint kindly pointed out, there is an article on wxWidgets' wiki. So according to that article two things need to happen. First override the EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND with an empty function.

```
void Canvas::EraseBackground( wxEraseEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
}
```

And second to implement a basic double buffering scheme. Here is how I did it.

```
void Canvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    int x, y;
    GetViewStart(&x, &y);
    wxRect Client_Area = GetClientRect();

    int width  = Client_Area.width;
    int height = Client_Area.height;

    wxBitmap Current = _Bitmap.GetSubBitmap(wxRect( x * 10, y * 10, width, height ));

    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.DrawBitmap(Current, 0, 0, false );
}
```

My scroll rate for both x and y is set to 10. That's why I multiply the view start coordinates.

Any more insight is very welcome.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: This looks like it might work.  However, it seems like you are copying your bitmap twice for every paint - once to Current and then from Current to the display context.  You may see an improvement if you use wxBufferedPaintDC, plus a reduction in the amount of code.

Comment: When I just do wxBufferedPaintDC dc(this); dc.DrawBitmap(_Bitmap, 0, 0, false ); it doesn't work. Can you tell me what's wrong? Thanks!